# each loop fail in jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

can anyone explain me what happen here??

i have this html code:

```
   <div class="calculadora">

      <div class="clear campos">
       <label>Amount</label>
       <input class="fi" id="amount" type="text" name="amount" value=""/>
      </div>

      <div class="clear campos">
       <label>Down Payment</label>
       <input class="fi" id="downPay" type="text" name="downPay" value=""/>
      </div>

      <div class="clear campos">
       <label>Years</label>
       <input class="fi" id="years" type="text" name="years" value=""/>
      </div>

      <div class="clear campos">
       <label>Rate</label>
       <input class="fi" id="rate" type="text" name="rate" value=""/>
      </div>

      <input id="cal" type="button" value="cacular"/>
      <div class="result"></div>
          </div>
```

And i'm making a jquery plugin, but i need to get all the attr('value') of each input, and i´m doing this way:

```
this.each(function(){

        var obj = $(this),
        vacio = parseFloat( $('.fi', obj).attr('value'));

       // some code...
```

But what happens it's that only get the first value of the first input... why??

BUT!! if i make this way :

```
var s = $('.fi', obj).each(function(){
             alert ($(this).attr('value'))
            });
```

it workss!!! Why?? this is good???

Tks in advance if anyone can explain to me.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this is your problem.  http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: Tks, it helps me to understand better the 'this' element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns the value of the specified attirbute from the first element in the collection is called upon.

From the doc:

> Get the value of an attribute **for the first element** in the set of matched elements.

When you make it *the other way*, you are extracting the value attribute data for each element in the matched set.

One way to achieve what you're after could be done by using the [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function, which returns a jquery array:

```
var vals = $('.fi', obj).map(function(){
    return this.value;
});
```

To transform it to a pure javascript array, you use `vals.toArray();`

Note: no need for jquery to get the value of an input because `this` in event handlers and in iteration on elements is the current DOMElement, so you can just do `this.value`.